# Permutation group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

let $G$ be a primitive permutation group of degree prime order $ p$, such that for stabilizers $ G_\alpha$ and $ G_\beta$ in $G$, $ G_\alpha\cap G_\beta=\{1\}$, prove $G$ is not simple.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Is $C_P$ with the obvious action not a counterexample to this?

Comment: How? please explain.

Comment: $C_P$ is a simple group, but with the usual action on $P$ elements, it is a primitive permutation group with all stabilizers trivial.

Comment: Well if the stabilizers are non-trivial this result is true, and follows because in a primitive permutation group, the stabilizers are maximum subgroups (and are of course all conjugate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following points are due to the book *Problems in Group Theory* by J.D.Dixon. So you can consider them as a bunch of hints leading us to the solution.

- If $[G:A]$ is finite then $[G:A\cap B]\le[G:A][G:B]$.
- If $G$ is a permutation primitive group on $\Omega$, then $|G|=p$ which $p$ is prime or $$\exists~\alpha\neq\beta\in\Omega,~~G=\langle G_{\alpha},G_{\beta}\rangle$$
- If $G$ is regular the claim is obvious, so think of $|G|$ and show that $|G|\leq p^2$.
- All $G_{\alpha}$s are conjugates since the action is transitive. And if $|\Omega|=p$ then $[G:G_{\alpha}]=p$ and so $p||G|$.
- And finally show that the $p-$sylow subgroup of $G$ is normal in the group.

Comment: You are making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be, I think.  The $G_\alpha$ are maximal, with trivial intersections.  They each have index $p$.  There are $p$ of them.  So $|\cup G_\alpha| = |G|-p+1$, and thus the subgroup of order $p$ is normal (contains all the elements fixing no points).